# iterable from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iterable

I need to create an iterable of the form (id, {feature name: features weight})  for using a python package.

my data are store in a pandas dataframe, here an example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3],
                    "gender":[1,0,1],
                    "age":[25,23,40]})
```

for the  {feature name: features weight}) part, I know I can use this:

```
fe = data.to_dict(orient='records')
Out[28]: 
[{'age': 25, 'gender': 1, 'id': 1},
 {'age': 23, 'gender': 0, 'id': 2},
 {'age': 40, 'gender': 1, 'id': 3}]
```

I know I can also iterate over the datframe for get the id, like this:

```
(row[1] for row in data.itertuples())
```

But I can get this two together to get one iterable (generator object )
I tried :

```
((row[1] for row in data.itertuples()),fe[i] for i in range(len(data)))
```

but the syntax is wrong.
Do you guys know how to do so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) returns named tuples. You can iterate and convert each row to a dictionary via the purpose-built method [`_asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict). You can wrap this in a generator function to create a lazy reader:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3],
                    "gender":[1,0,1],
                    "age":[25,23,40]})

def gen_rows(df):
    for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
        yield row._asdict()

G = gen_rows(data)

print(next(G))  # OrderedDict([('age', 25), ('gender', 1), ('id', 1)])
print(next(G))  # OrderedDict([('age', 23), ('gender', 0), ('id', 2)])
print(next(G))  # OrderedDict([('age', 40), ('gender', 1), ('id', 3)])
```

Note that the result will be [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) objects. As a subclass of `dict`, for most purposes this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think need first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column `id` and then [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='index'`:

```
fe = data.set_index('id', drop=False).to_dict(orient='index')
print (fe)
{1: {'id': 1, 'gender': 1, 'age': 25}, 
 2: {'id': 2, 'gender': 0, 'age': 23},
 3: {'id': 3, 'gender': 1, 'age': 40}}
```

Comment: this work too! thanks ! I just add ((i, v) for i, v in fe.items()) to have an iterable.

Comment: @blabla - Glad can help!